# Stop curly braces from being dropped onto a new line (enclosure functions)

Tags: php, phpcs

I have an example code below:

```
$class->doA("something", function () {})
    ->doB("something else", function () {});
```

When I run formatter PHPCS changes my code from above to:

```
$class->doA("something", function () {
})
    ->doB("something else", function () {
    });
```

What I want is for my code to stay the same. If my enclosure was to have some code, then I would have wanted to keep code within enclosure indented too, as shown below:

```
$class->doA("something", function () {
        return 1 + 1;
    })
    ->doB("something else", function () {});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly. You want empty functions to be on one line? What PHP version do you use? Is arrow syntax an option?